# LINQ query results not filtered when mocking IOrganizationService (Dynamics CRM)

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, dynamics-crm, moq

I am having a problem unit testing my code that queries Dynamics CRM 2015.

I use the Moq framework and mock the `IOrganizationService` as follows:

```
IList<Account> accounts = new List<Account> {/*...*/};
IList<IEntity> expected = new List<Entity>(accounts);
var collection = new EntityCollection(expected);
var retrieveMultipleResponse = new RetrieveMultipleResponse
{
    Results = new ParameterCollection
    {
        { "EntityCollection", collection}
    }
};
var mockOrganizationService = new Mock<IOrganizationService>();
mockOrganizationService.Setup(os => os.Execute(
    It.IsAny<RetrieveMultipleRequest>())).Returns(retrieveMultipleResponse);
```

So, the `IOrganizationService` mock would always return the same predefined list of accounts, no matter what the request is like.

This is the code I am trying to test:

```
var query = serviceContext.AccountSet.Where(
                a => a.AccountId != null && a.AccountId.Value == guid)
var account = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

When this code is executed against a real CRM instance, it works as expected.

Using a mocked `IOrganizationService`, the code does not work anymore. In the debugger, I can see that AccountSet returns the expected account list (the one I set up during mocking). However, the `Where` method does not seem to get executed, and `query` contains all the account entities. So, the call to `FirstOrDefault` returns only the first one, and not the result of calling the `Where` method.

If I modify the code as follows, it also starts working during unit testing:

```
var query = serviceContext.AccountSet.ToList().Where(
                    a => a.AccountId != null && a.AccountId.Value == guid)
var account = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

If I understand correctly, this code retrieves all the accounts, and filters them locally (not in CRM). This is fine for unit testing, but this would not be acceptable in the real application.

Could anyone please advise what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

**Edit**:

We ended up mocking `serviceContext` instead because we call methods (or properties) on it directly from the client code, and not the ones on `IOrganizationService`. I think that mocking `IOrganizationService` should only make sense if the code we want to test uses `IOrganizationService` directly and not via `serviceContext`. Otherwise, we have something like two-level mocking, and it becomes messy.

Comment: You are correct. After the ToList() statement all rows are retrieved and your are using Linq To Objects to filter the items. The implementation of the CRM linq provider is buggy and not complete. Do never expect that using a moq will always give the same result as the "real" implementation.

Comment: Show some more of details about the code you are trying to test as it relates to `serviceContext.AccountSet` so that a [mcve] will allow for better ability to replicate your issue

Comment: @JeroenHeier, that's one of the many reasons by which I started [FakeXrmEasy](http://dynamicsvalue.com/get-started/overview). This auto-mocking framework will give you a much closer experience to the behavior of a "real" organization service... and without using any mocks at all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` clause becomes a part of the query executed against the `OrganizationService` which in your case is mocked to always return the full `accounts` list regardless of conditions. You could add more logic to your moq, but generally that's not necessary in unit tests as your goal is to test your business logic and not your ability to mock the `OrganizationService`.

Comment: Hi Matt, keep in mind that an essential part of any business logic are queries too... with many joins, and filters... Example: When you work with many plugins or codeactivities, which need to perform queries to retrieve X records to perform X actions against them, then you need a mock per query basically, because you need to return a different list of entities in each case.

Comment: @Jordi I agree the queries are very important, but they can only really be tested with integration and functional tests against actual data, not a mock. If you're writing a unit test your focus is going to be on your biz logic and not the CRUD operations against the orgservice.

Comment: Hi @Matt, did you try FakeXrmEasy? It has a query engine which runs Fetch, QueryByAttribute, LINQ, and QueryExpressions. Its purpose is to be able to unit tests those queries before integration testing too. [Here](http://dynamicsvalue.com/blog/fake-xrm-easy-versus-other-frameworks) is a link which compares queries run from FakeXrmEasy as opposed to other mocking frameworks. Any feedback would be more than welcome! :)

Comment: @Jordi that's pretty cool, I hadn't heard of it before seeing your answer to this question. Seems very useful.

Comment: Actually, we ended up mocking `serviceContext` instead because we call methods (or properties) on it directly from the client code, and not the ones on `IOrganizationService`. I think that mocking `IOrganizationService` should only make sense if the code we want to test use `IOrganizationService` directly and not via `serviceContext`. Otherwise, we have something like two-level mocking, and it becomes messy.

Comment: Sorry just reading this... not really! By mocking the IOrganizationService which is pretty low level, the serviceContext is gonna use your already mocked messages. So no need 2 levels of mocking... Example: https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/master/FakeXrmEasy.Tests.Shared/FakeContextTests/LinqTests/FakeContextTestLinqQueries.cs#L29-L31

Answer (score 2):

Please give a try to [FakeXrmEasy](http://dynamicsvalue.com/home). There are some introduction videos and many different testing examples.

By using FakeXrmEasy mocks are already handled by the framework, therefore reducing the amount of boilerplate code just to setup your test.

I've been working on it since 2014, and it is MIT licensed. Actually, if anyone would like to contribute to the project it would be super awesome! :)

**EDIT**: Just [adding a link](http://dynamicsvalue.com/blog/fake-xrm-easy-versus-other-frameworks) to a blog post which compares FakeXrmEasy against other .NET mocking frameworks.  The purpose is nothing but to be able to have as many work done for Dynamics CRM as possible. With other .NET mocking frameworks there is basically too much to mock, every single time.